# Find Lowest Value in Columns Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table in Access 2010 that has 3 separate priority fields. I have a sub that looks through the columns, finds the smallest number, and puts it in an `Overall Priority` field.

Ex.

```
SubProjNo    |   GOPri   |   StrPri    | SOPri
--------+-----------+----------+------------------

1234-12-01    |   100   |        7     |   61

1234-12-02    |         |       18     |   2

1234-12-03    |   51    |              |

ProjNo: 1234-12-00      Overall_Priority:2
```

I originally had the code under `Private Sub Form_Current()` but it slowed the program down way too much, so I moved it to an `AfterUpdate` for the subform that the table is in.

```
Private Sub MFWorkProjectssubform_AfterUpdate()
Dim MinGOPri As Variant
Dim MinStrPri As Variant
Dim MinSOPri As Variant

MinGOPri = DMin("[GOPri]", "[WorkProjects]", "WorkProjects.PROJNO = Activity.PROJNO")
MinStrPri = DMin("[StrPri]", "[WorkProjects]", "WorkProjects.PROJNO = Activity.PROJNO")
MinSOPri = DMin("[SOPri]", "[WorkProjects]", "WorkProjects.PROJNO = Activity.PROJNO")

Overall_Priority = IIf(((IIf([MinGOPri] < [MinStrPri], [MinGOPri], [MinStrPri])))
< [MinSOPri], ((IIf([MinGOPri] < [MinStrPri], [MinGOPri], [MinStrPri]))), [MinSOPri])

End Sub
```

The problem is, now, all the columns are cleared and only the largest value is left. Any suggestions for how to get this to work, or how to speed it up if I put it back in `Form_Current` would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is `1234-12-01` a unique value for this table? Another way to put this: does `SubProjNo` have a unique index in this table?

Comment: Yes, each project and subproject is identified by a unique number

Comment: Looking at your question and some of the answers, I'm very confused. **What are we trying to do here?** Are we trying to get the `SubProjNo` and its' absolute lowest value in *any* of the columns, for the whole table? The current upvoted solution suggests that you use that solution in a query to essentially create a "view" and use that as your recordsource. I feel like you're not sure what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to get the lowest value from the three priority columns for the entire `ProjNo`. I managed to get it to work using a query as that answer suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all this. For the Overall_Priority textbox use this expression as ControlSource:

```
=IIf(((IIf([GOPri]<[StrPri],[GOPri],[StrPri])))<[SOPri],((IIf([GOPri]<[StrPri],[GOPri],[StrPri]))),[SOPri])
```

Edit for Null and reduced:

```
=IIf(IIf(Nz([GOPri],9999)<Nz([StrPri],9999),Nz([GOPri],9999),Nz([StrPri],9999))<Nz([SOPri],9999),IIf(Nz([GOPri],9999)<Nz([StrPri],9999),Nz([GOPri],9999),Nz([StrPri],9999)),Nz([SOPri],9999))
```

Use this as a fourth column; name it, say, RowMin.

Then, in the footer, use =Min([RowMin]) as the controlsource for your totals box.

Comment: `OveralPriority` is the current ControlSource for this textbox. It's an actual value that needs to be calculated from the table, if that makes sense. Changing the ControlSource gives a `#Value?` error.

Comment: Yes, I missed that you have Nulls. Edited.

Comment: It still gives `#Name?` when the columns are blank. When they're not, it gives a run-time error 2447: Invalid use of the . or ! operator or invalid parenthesis.

Comment: Then something else is going on. The syntax is correct. Reduce it bit by bit until you see no error. Then correct. Also, empty fields must be Null, not empty strings.

Comment: I think the empty fields _are_ empty strings, though.

Comment: But then the values are also strings, not numbers. Replace the Nz construct with an IIf construct.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: My code is correct and works here so, again, something else is going on beyond what we know here.

Comment: I missed you need the minimum for all "cells" so you could use Min() as showed above.

Comment: So I'm having a little trouble with the second part. The RowMin column works fine, but I can't seem to get a totals box working, or have it update the `OverallPriority` box.

Comment: Can you use   =Min(Nz([GOPri],0))   ?

Comment: Then you could move the long IIf expression to the query you use as source and use your original method using DMin to pull the field.

Comment: I'm very slow today - what, exactly, do you mean?

Comment: In you DMin expression, replace WorkProjects with a query that selects this plus a column with the long IIf expression.

Comment: The original method slows Access down too much for me to use.

Comment: Maybe. But you used three DMin and not one.

Answer (score 1):

How about using recordsets, is this an option ?

```
Dim rst As Object
Dim minValue As Integer
Dim fieldCounter As Long
Dim minPriority as Long
minPriority = 9999
Set rst = Me.recordsetclone

With rst
    .MoveFirst
    While Not .EOF
        For fieldCounter = 0 To .Fields.Count-1  
        if(.Fields(fieldcounter).name = "GOPri" or .Fields(fieldcounter).name = "StrPri" or .Fields(fieldcounter).name = "SOPri" ) then
        Debug.print "Now you are checking : " &.Fields(fieldcounter).Name & " with value : " & .Fields(fieldcounter) & " Current minPriority = " & minPriority
            If len(Nz(.Fields(fieldCounter),"")) > 0 Then
                If .Fields(fieldCounter) < minPriority Then minPriority = .Fields(fieldCounter)
            End If
        End if
        Next
        .MoveNext
    Wend
End With
Set rst = Nothing
Overall_Priority = minPriority
```

Maybe you need to adjust the fieldCounter to match your Table structure
The fields are counted from 0 -->.... according to your question.

```
 Fields(0) = SubProjNo  
 Field(1) = GoPRi
```

Comment: This is flagging a syntax error at `If len(Nz(fields(fieldsCounter),"") > 0 Then`.

Comment: probably something is mistyped...have you copy paste it ?...can you give me  more info....maybe your table structure is a bit different...

Comment: I copy/pasted it. First it gave an error at `minPriority=9999` so I added `Dim minPriority as Integer`.  I also changed `fieldCounter = 1` to `= 13` because GOPri is the 13th column in the table - I just left out the others in my example to simplify it.

Comment: If GOpri is the 13th column then the fieldcounter should be :     fieldcounter = 12 to .Fields.count-1. It would be easier to send me a database with only the table inside to test it myself.....thanks for spotting the lack of minPriority declaration...i edited the post

Comment: It's still giving me a syntax error in the same place.

Comment: So I did a bit of tinkering with the code - mostly swapping Integers for Longs - and it seems to be technically working... except it's giving me a priority of -1217365 instead of 7... It also seems to be slowing down the reports, which was my original problem.

Comment: You should check which value you are comparing each time.I will edit my answer to show you how to check the values in the immediate window

Comment: I can't tell if it's working or not... it's slowing the program down so much that it freezes between records...

Comment: first things first...do you get a correct result? If this is ok maybe you should check other techniques to speed up your report? maybe a local table if you are using a linked table,also how many records are we talking about ?

Comment: The result still isn't correct. It's still filling in -1217365. We're talking about over a thousand records.

Comment: attach a database with the table....probably something in the structure ...is SOPri the last column of you table ?

Comment: The database has a lot of sensitive information, so I can't share it. It's not the last column; There's about ten after it.

Comment: Now it's filling it in as 9999, and it's still very slow.

Comment: i need some debugging info from immediate window

Answer (score 1):

If you want this column to always be a function of the other three fields, then you could create a calculated field to the table.  The help documents can show you how; also this article gives directions:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3

Generally you would define a new field on the table and set it's formula to the maximum of the other three fields.  Then any time the calculated field is referenced it will always give you the maximum of them.

The other option is to just not worry about saving the field at all at the time of data entry and simply create a view that adds a field defined to be the maximum of the three values.